# Create an image dark overlay at top of an image

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML where in my banner has a background image:

```
<header>
        <div class="banner">

                                
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                                </p>

        </div>
    </header>
```

On my CSS:

```
.banner {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/pXsKCUt.jpg');
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
```

Now I am trying to add a dark overly on my image background so what I did is that I used `:before` property:

```
    .banner:before {
background-color: black
width: 100%;
height: auto;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

However, this did not added the dark background overlay at the top of the image.

How can I achieve this in CSS?

Comment: I think you might just be missing content:""; in the .banner:before class in your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `content` property to the pseudo-element and then position the pseudo-element absolutely over it's parent.

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/pXsKCUt.jpg');
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}

.banner:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="banner">


    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    </p>

  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/pXsKCUt.jpg");
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}

.banner::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.banner p {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way of doing it by adding the text to the css content instead of having it be a paragraph element. All I did was cut the text and place it into the css. (and change text to white for readability)

This isn't the *best* way to do it, but it is a way to do it.

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/pXsKCUt.jpg');
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.banner:before {
    content:"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="banner">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</header>
```